# postgres substring escape open bracket character

Tags: postgresql, escaping, postgresql-9.3, brackets

I am trying to return all characters within brackets from a string field in postgres:

This function seems to work well:

```
 select substring('foo bar [foobar] foo' from '%#"f%b#"%' for '#');
 substring
-----------
 foob
```

It will not work with an open bracket character:

```
select substring('foo bar [foobar] foo' from '%#"[%]#"%' for '#');
substring
-----------
```

The close bracket works fine, 
I've tried backslash, double backslash, period, single quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape brackets as they are metacharacters:

```
select substring('foo bar [foobar] foo' from '%#"#[%#]#"%' for '#');

 substring 
-----------
 [foobar]
(1 row)
```

or

```
select substring('foo bar [foobar] foo' from '%#[#"%#"#]%' for '#');

 substring 
-----------
 foobar
(1 row)
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP):

> In addition to these facilities borrowed from LIKE, SIMILAR TO supports these pattern-matching metacharacters borrowed from POSIX regular expressions:
>
> ...
>
> - A bracket expression [...] specifies a character class, just as in POSIX regular expressions.